# docker storage backend and container-generated data storage

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, okd, unionfs

I am learning about Docker storage and I am little bit confused about

**Question 1** : 

Do we have for each docker host 1 backend store ( to store layers of images and writable-layers of containers ) ?

and if we configure a container-generated data store ( to persist the data wrote by a container (Volumes,Bind mounts,tmpfs mounts) ) are we going have 2 stores ( backend and container-generated-data store ) or is it just one store ?

**Question 2** : suppose we have configured a volume to persist container-generated data , is it still gonning to be a a union fs layer somewhere else that is going to be persisted even if the container is removed ?

**Question 3** : containers are runnable images , but concretly can you explain to me what are they ? are they just a unionFs layer ?

**Question 4** : 
if we uninstall or stop docker is the thin pool on loopback device saved or is it removed ?
 and what if we configure a thin pool on a logical volume and we uninstall docker will we still have the images and the container-generated data on the logical volume ?

**Question 5** : how do we configure docker to use a group volume ( or a logical volume ) in a remote machine ?

**Question 6** : what is the different between the persistant storage configured for kubernetes/okd/openshift cluser and the persistant storage configured for docker and does the configuration for docker storage conflict with the one of kubernetes ?
https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/persistent_storage/index.html
https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/persistent_storage/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer 1 :

Yes we have one and only one docker backend storage for each docker host

1. backend store : is used to store only the images and the container layer
2. volumes

   - if volume bind : then store in filesystem else in :
   - /var/lib/docker/volumes/

3 . Bind mounts : stored anywhere on the host system 
4 . tmpfs mounts : stored anywhere on the host system

### Answer 2 :

volumes are not used to persist all the container layer but a specific folder

### Answer 3 :

containers are just layers on top of the image layer where the process that it runs are isolated using

### Answer 4 :

writable layer using backend store on loop back device is ephemeral so it won't be persisted after stop of docker container nore uninstall of docker engine.

### Answer 5 :

use SAN or NAS

### Answer 6 :

docker storage is used to store images and container
kubernetes is used to persist data of containers